# How to create Switch in Formik

Tags: reactjs, antd, formik

I would like to create Switch component using Formik. The design of tooltip I took from antd library and the basic use of it looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Switch } from 'antd';

const onChange = (checked) => {
  console.log(`switch to ${checked}`);
};

const App = () => <Switch defaultChecked onChange={onChange} />;

export default App;
```

How to combine this with Formik?

Answer (score 0):

**Need to use `Switch` from *"formik-antd"*.**

Please check the working example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-switch-with-formik-ejwpuf?file=/src/App.js:103-116).